# Google App Engine: Код работает в IE6, но не работает в Firefox 4.0

Tags: python, firefox, javascript, internet-explorer, google-app-engine

```
function login_to_create() {
    var HttpRequest = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        HttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        HttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (!HttpRequest) {
        document.getElementById('messageDiv').innerHTML="AJAX not supported"; 
        return;  
    }
    HttpRequest.open('POST','/check');
    HttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((200 == HttpRequest.status) && (4 == HttpRequest.readyState)) {
            if (HttpRequest.responseText != 'OK')
                document.getElementById('messageDiv').innerHTML="<b><font color='FFFFFF'>Incorrect user or password</font><b>";
            else
                window.location.href="/create";
         }
    }
    HttpRequest.send('user='  + document.getElementById('user').value + ';pass=' + document.getElementById('pass').value);
}
```

На стороне сервера:

```
class Check(webapp.RequestHandler):
      def post(self):
        user  = self.request.get('user')
        passw = self.request.get('pass')
        if ('test' == user):
           self.response.out.write('OK')       
        else:
           self.response.out.write('Bad')
```

В Firefox приходит (пробовал alert'ами) пустой ответ. Код должен отправлять на сервер user и pass, и получать ОК, если user == 'test'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашлось решение. Пропущена строка:

```
HttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

После:

```
HttpRequest.open
```